# Clickhouse, engine for fast Joins

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, columnstore, clickhouse

Is there and engine in clickhouse that is optimized for fast join, that could be used similarly to how one would use mariaDB column sotrage (e.g. have the big tables be column stored and then samaler tables... eg 50GB, innoDB) ?

Comment: What is Clickhouse?

Comment: Rick James - clickhouse it's a fast open-source column database http://clickhouse.yandex/reference_en.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@George
try use Dictonaries https://clickhouse.yandex/reference_en.html#Dictionaries and MergeTree family database engine https://clickhouse.yandex/reference_en.html#MergeTree